# C++ class not printing?

Tags: c++, class

I'mm getting a bit confused why this isn't printing the name!
I've got a human.cpp :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "human.h"

human::human(int age, human *n){
m_age=age;
name = new char[2];

human::~human() = default;

void human::printDetails(){
    std::cout <<"name is      " << name << " age is " << m_age << std::endl;
}
```

and human.h:

```
class human {
    public: //: needed
        human(int age, human *name);
        ~human();
        void printDetails();
    private :
        char *name;
        int m_age;

};
```

and finally the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "human.h"

int main()

{
    human *Alex = new human(10, Alex); //pointer // needs argument //should have both age and name
    Alex->printDetails(); //print not Print

    }
```

So my issue is: it prints the age, but does not print the name? Any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: What's `human::~human() = default;`? What does it do?

Comment: The code you should doesn't even build. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To make matters worse, you probably have some misunderstandings about the assignment, and what you're supposed to do. My *guess* is that you should pass the name of the "human" as a *string* to the constructor.

Comment: Do you have Java background?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for any `new` in your code. Since you `#include`d `<string>` in your code I assume you want to use it:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
    int age;
    std::string name;

public:
    Person(int age, std::string name)
    : age  {  age },
      name { name }
    {}

    int get_age() const { return age; }
    std::string const& get_name() const { return name; }

    void print_details() const {
        std::cout << "My name is " << name << ". I am " << age << " years old.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p{ 19, "Alex" };
    p.print_details();
}
```

---

If you *really* want to do it the hard way<sup>tm</sup>:

```
#include <cstring>  // std::strlen()
#include <utility>  // std::exchange(), std::swap()
#include <iostream>

class Person
{
    char *name_;
    int   age_;

public:
    Person(int age, char const *name)  // constructor
                       // we don't want to call std::strlen() on a nullptr
                       // instead allocate just one char and set it '\0'.
    : name_ { new char[name ? std::strlen(name) + 1 : 1]{} },
      age_  { age }
    {
        if (name)
            std::strcpy(name_, name);
    }

    Person(Person const &other)  // copy-constructor
    : name_ { new char[std::strlen(other.name_) + 1] },
      age_  { other.age_ }
    {
        std::strcpy(name_, other.name_);
    }

    Person(Person &&other) noexcept  // move-constructor
    : name_ { std::exchange(other.name_, nullptr) },  // since other will be
      age_  { other.age_ }                            // wasted anyway, we
    {}                                                // "steal" its resource

    Person& operator=(Person other) noexcept  // copy-assignment operator
    {                                   // since the parameter other got
        std::swap(name_, other.name_);  // copied and will be destructed
        age_ = other.age_;              // at the end of the function we
        return *this;                   // can simply swap  the pointers
    }                                   // - know as the copy&swap idiom.

    ~Person() { delete[] name_; }  // destructor

    void print_details() const
    {
        std::cout << "I am " << name_ << ". I am " << age_ << " years old.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p{ 19, "Alex" };
    p.print_details();
}
```

If you don't want to implement the special member functions you'd have to `= delete;` them so the compiler-generated versions - which won't work correctly for classes managing their own resources - won't get called by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're confused with the second parameter of the `human` constructor. Look at this changes:

human.h

```
class human {
public:
    human(int age, char *name);
    human(const human& h);
    human& operator=(const human& h);
    void printDetails();
    virtual ~human();
private:
    int age;
    char *name;
};
```

human.cpp

```
human::human(int _age, char *_name) {
    age = _age;
    name = new char[strlen(_name)+1];
    strcpy(name, _name);
}

human::human(const human& _h) { //Copy constructor
    age = _h.age;
    name = new char[strlen(_h.name)+1];
    strcpy(name, _h.name);
}

human& human::operator=(const human& _h) { //Copy assignment operator
    age = _h.age;
    name = new char[strlen(_h.name)+1];
    strcpy(name, _h.name);
    return *this;
}

void human::printDetails(){
    std::cout <<"name is " << name << " age is " << age << std::endl;
}

human::~human() { //Destructor
    delete[] name;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {

    human *alex = new human(10, "Alex");
    alex->printDetails();

    human *anotherAlex = new human(*alex);
    anotherAlex->printDetails();

    delete alex;
    delete anotherAlex;
}
```

**A suggestions:** I would use `Human` as the class names and `alex` for the variable names. (See how I capitalized them)

Comment: @Swordfish Can you tell me more. is it about how I used `strcpy`?

Comment: Down to one buffer overflow (you want to copy "Alex" which is 5 `char`s into a buffer 2 `char`s big) and 1 memory leak with your last edit. (and one copyright infringement with your avatar ;p)

Comment: Now some cracy guy does `human susi{ *Alex };` ==> double `delete`.

Comment: @Swordfish Hey dude, I know how to please myself by using `std::string` and I was trying to do the minimum changes to make the code works. (and my avatar is fine)

Comment: He was talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: @ChristianG Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianG Do you like the new code? (assuming the OP wants to use `char*` instead of `std::string`)

Comment: @Emadpres copy ctor and assignment should have *const* human& _h parameter

Comment: @Emadpres You need to change the definitions of copy-ctor and assignment-operator as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <new>

    using namespace std;

    class human {
        public: 
            human(int age, const char * name)
            {
                m_age=age;
                m_name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
                strcpy(m_name,name);
            }
            ~human()
{
delete[] m_name;
}
            void printDetails()
            {
                std::cout <<"name is      " << m_name << " age is " << m_age << std::endl;
            }
        private :
            char *m_name;
            int m_age;

    };

    int main()
    {

        human *Alex = new human(10, "alex"); //pointer // needs argument //should have both age and name
        Alex->printDetails(); //print not Print
        delete Alex;
        return 0;
    }
```

You need to read more. The example you shared was wrong at many level, also read about dynamic memory management.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score -1):

For beginner you may use std::string, so you already included it. ))

human.h

```
#include <string>
class human
{
    public: //: needed
        human(int age, std::string name);
        void printDetails();
    private :
        std::string name;
        int m_age;
};
```

human.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "human.h"

human::human(int age, std::string n)
{
    m_age = age;
    name = n;
}

void human::printDetails()
{
    std::cout <<"name is: " << name << " age is: " << m_age << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "human.h"

int main()

{
    human *Alex = new human(10, "Alex");
    Alex->printDetails();

}
```

Comment: One memory leak, unjustified use of dynamic memory allocation and pointers, no use of the initializer list. Why do especially "beginners" use `std::string`?

Comment: This is an example of the author, I answered his question. std :: string was invented because it is inconvenient to work with char *, and even more so for a beginner. Why minus the normal meaningful answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: I looked at your answer, for a novice to a novice newcomer, but there are no less problems there than in the author's question. Nobody can write to you about this, because for a comment, a rating of 50 is needed, and people like you don't let people lift it)))

Comment: "I looked at your answer, [...], but there are no less problems there than in the author's question." Which problems? "people like you don't let people lift it" People like me?? Again: I did NOT downvote your answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you did. We simultaneously wrote the same answer. I did not consider it as a resume on hiring a developer C ++, so I did not change all the problem areas of the author. The meaning is the same - do not use char *, use std :: string. This is the main idea. You consider your answer to be normal, mine criticized.

I'm not saying that you put it. It was put by the same person as you.

Comment: "It was put by the same person as you." it is not very nice how you "categorize" people you don't even know. My first comment on your answer was meant to help you on how to improve it.